# Eclipse regex matching for ending strings

Tags: regex, eclipse

In my code I have some strings as follows:

```
blabla AS myString, blabla
```

I'd like to capture **AS myString,** only, but the regex I'm using now captures everything after the comma. I already enabled the checkbox for regex in the Find/Replace window, so my regex is:

```
AS\s[^"]+(,)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this code snippet part of a SQL query, and, if so, can you let us know why you are trying to match the alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[^"]+(,)` part matches any 1 or more chars other than `"`, *as many as possible*, up to the `,` char. That means all commas before the first `"` are grabbed, too.

You may modify the pattern to use

```
AS\s+[^",]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KEVGkQ/1).

To match `AS` as a whole word you may add a word boundary:

```
\bAS\s+[^",]+
^^
```

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `AS` - a literal string
- `\s+`  - one or more whitespace chars
- `[^",]+` - one or more chars other than `"` and `,`.